# Raspberry pi zero 2w and usb c hub

Tags: usb-hub, pi-zero-w-2, usb-c, otg

I have a raspi zero 2w and inside flirc case and using 4year old 16gb sd card and headless pi os; it uses usb micro to usb c and then usb c to ethernet.
I wanted to transfer some files from pi to my laptop but its quite slow maybe due to my old router or sd card read/write performance as well. I was thinking of connecting a usb c hub which consist of ethernet and usb a ports, is this possible ?